# How to set product store view fields to default with use_default[]?

Tags: api

I see the use_default[] field name used in the product editor page source, and figure it would be a fantastically simple and direct way of achieving precisely what it does via the API, rather than having to do so in the admin UI for each product individually, especially being that Magento is so painfully slow. However that doesn't actually seem to work.

Anyone know how to set which product fields are to inherit default values per store view via the API in PHP?